# Is it possible to achieve this goal? Asking strong chess players

Tags: study

I am 14 years old. Several months ago, I was introduced to chess. I loved the game, and it quickly became all I think about. I only learned the rules of chess at 11/12 and only played it from 8 months ago, but I taught myself so many things and I am now a 2300 rated player. In only 8 months, I changed from a complete beginner who only played 3 or 4 games in his life, to a relatively okay player(2300). I did this on my own. Is this the beginning of a meteoric rise of my chess strength? Am I destined to be at the top of the world? Or am I living in a dream that will never materialize? I am aware that today's top players learned chess at 6/7, and that as we go into the future, this standard will be inevitably rendered too old, but is it possible that I can do it? I am learning new things everyday, and if I were to look at my games a week ago, I would laugh at how weak I am. Am I going to be a great exception? I know Rubinstein learned chess when he was 16. Please answer me fast.

I have no intentions of bragging about myself, but know that:

I did many IQ tests and scored the highest possible score on almost all  of them.

I did many memory test that all my family members couldn't finish which I did easily.

I also believe I have a big talent for chess and thinking.

I played many beautiful games.

Comment: 2300, but what rating system?  USCF? FIDE? Something else?  Is the rating provisional? How many rated games have you played?

Comment: I don't believe the story, I think @John is a daydreamer. Typical for a 14 year old kid. Not even Carlsen could rise to 2300 in his first 8 months. Are you sure you are not talking about 1300?

Comment: I am not lying. I am not a daydreamer. I will be World Champion before 2025. And when I be World Champion, I will talk about this story. My first name starts with an 'A' and my last name starts with an 'S.'

Comment: I am of 2300 strength. It is true that I do not have a rating, but I beat 2 coaches each rated around 2100-2200. I also have a 2300 rating on 3 chess websites.

Comment: I should have used the term strength instead of rating. It would take me some time to reach a 2300 rating, the number itself, but my strength is 2300. By the time I have a 2300 rating, I will be even stronger. I used the number 2300 because I saw 2200 players making very bad mistakes in my chess club, and because I still don't think I am as strong as an IM.

Comment: What country do you live in?  if you have not played a rated tournament, you have no rating. Defeating strong opponents in a non-rated setting does not give you a rating.

Comment: tell us the chess website and username to confirm, because 2300 in 8 months is unheard of. Carlsen took almost 2 years from 2000(not beginner) to 2300.

Answer (score 7):

I feel that this is a troll post due to the language.

I can say this immediately. The rating system that you are using is not a USCF or FIDE rated system with over the board play and/or you have a provisional rating and have not played a proper amount of game to accurately gauge your strength.

It is possible to obtain almost a Class A strength in that time span if you have both a natural talent AND near obsessive study with guidance. However, reaching master strength during that time span is impossible even for the most gifted of students. Carlsen is a perfect example as many other people have noted. It took him 2 years simply to go from Candidate Master to Fide Master strength.

Note: I am a professional chess instructor and I've been teaching chess as my primary profession and sole source of income for 10 years.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of information that you refuse to give here.

For example, you explain that you have 'played beautiful games', but do not show any examples of such games.

You claim that you have '2300' rating, and yet you again refuse to show what standard of rating it is. It's not hard to type 'FIDE' or 'USCF' and yet you hide that information for some reason.
On the same grounds, I could tell you that I am 2800, 'higher' than Magnus Calsen.

This clandestine manner in which you present your so called merits, coupled with the unrealistic circumstances makes you a very suspicious character.

If you truly had been able to achieve what you claim, the newspapers would most likely have posted about you.

So, all in all, change the manner in which you show your specifications, or stop dreaming and realize that reality has boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

If you made 2300 FIDE (or even USCF) in 8 months then I'd say you have an excellent chance of becoming a Grand Master. The top 50 players in the world are pretty strong (and motivated) so who can say if you can ever be at the top. You'll have to decide you want it, and go for it.

But 2300 with under a year of experience is really *really* unusual. Fischer 'got good' at about your age, but he'd been playing seriously for a few years by then, against good players. And he had an instructor.

To continue improving, you'll need an instructor and IM-level competition. Find a local chess club of that strength and play there.

Comment: My father doesn't want me to pursue chess as a profession, all I can do is buy books and read them. I am reading Fundamental Chess Endings and Fundamental Chess Openings. I will buy Kramnik's book and My System. The only way I will get to do what I want is to be successful in a strong tournament, which luckily one happens in my area every year. I once proposed the possibility of leaving school to become a chess player, but the response was nothing you'd want to know of.

Comment: Don't leave school. Go to your chess club and talk to IMs. See what they do for a living. You'll find 95% of them do not play chess for a living.